# Merging ndarray image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have an image as an `ndarray` with a shape of `(2000, 2000, 3)`. In a next step a split the channels to do some work on them:

```
image_r = (image_color[:,:,0])
image_g = (image_color[:,:,1])
image_b = (image_color[:,:,2])
```

When the work is done I need to merge the channels to one image. How do I do that?

I tried to generate an empty image `full_image = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), 3)` And to append the channels to it. But this didn't work out.

I also tried to stack the values using the hstack.

```
full_image = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
full_image = np.hstack(full_image, image_r)
full_image = np.hstack(full_image, image_g)
full_image = np.hstack(full_image, image_b)
```

But this didn't work out either. With the following error:

```
full_image = np.hstack(full_image, image_r)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in hstack
TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Consider showing the error for the first attempt too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack the arrays along the third axis:

```
full_image = np.dstack([image_r, image_g, image_b])
```

---

```
image_color = np.random.randint(0,255,(2000, 2000, 3))

image_r = (image_color[:,:,0])
image_g = (image_color[:,:,1])
image_b = (image_color[:,:,2])

np.dstack([image_r, image_g, image_b]).shape
# (2000, 2000, 3)
```

Comment: does dstack keep the order?

Comment: Yes sure, it stacks according to the order of its input @JürgenK.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts didn't work out because you are not using the available tools quite right. Both approaches you tried are sound with a couple of minor modifications.

`zeros` requires a single tuple to describe the array size, not two separate arguments:

```
 full_image = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3))
 full_image[..., 0] = image_r
 full_image[..., 1] = image_g
 full_image[..., 2] = image_b
```

`hstack` concatenates along the second dimension. You want to concatenate along the third, so either use `dstack` or just `stack`. In either case, the first argument is a tuple containing *all* the arrays you want to concatenate:

```
full_image = np.dstack((image_r, image_g, image_b))
```

or

```
full_image = np.stack((image_r, image_g, image_b), axis=2)
```

You could even use `concatenate`, but I really don't recommend it. `concatenate` accepts a tuple of all the arrays you want to join, like `stack`, but it operates on a dimension that already exists, so you have to make one:

```
full_image = np.concatenate((image_r[..., None], image_g[..., None], image_b[..., None]), axis=2)
```